# MySQL query won't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to run that query for quite some time now yet "won" isn't being set to a decimal value regardless of if I use quotes on the value or not.

```
UPDATE trans 
   SET `outtrans` = 'test1', 
       `won` = '23.00043' 
  WHERE `intrans`='test1'
```

If I change the value of `outtrans` to a different one, it says 1 rows affected.  Yet if I do the same for `won`, it says 0 rows affected.

I am not using any APIs, just vanilla mysql.

Comment: I don't think you quote column names.

Comment: what's the datatype of the `won` column?

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify, it's decimal

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. Is it `NUMERIC`?

Comment: DECIMAL is a perfectly specific data type in mysql @tadman

Comment: @EricJablow, no, he is not quoting columns but backticking them, which is a recommended practice.

Comment: @Sebas: It's not recommended, the opposite -- it means you're using MySQL keywords for column and/or table names

Comment: @OMGPonies the list of reserved keywords is 2 kilometers long. It is very advicable to always backtick to 1- be sure you don't get bad surprises and 2- improve readability (subjective point of view for this one, for me it helps). i WANT to have a `DEFAULT` and `CHECK` columns in my tables.

Comment: If you backtick all column and table names you will never have conflicts with keywords. Some of the reserved keywords are obnoxious to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting your time guys, turned out the table I was trying to set as decimal was int and another column was decimal instead. Thanks for all the effort.

Comment: This is why posting your schema, or at least the relevant parts, is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric suggested, remove the quotations from the column names.  Also, so into the table structure and make sure the length/value for you decimal column is set to house stuff after the decimal point.  For example, i just built a test table to work on this and despite  having the column set to decimal, the default length was 10,0, the 0 indicating no storage of digits after the decimal point.  I changed it to 10,4 and all was good.